# Given $S=1+3+5+\cdots+2017+2019$, find $\frac{1}{1010}S-1008$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic

I'm wrong, or the answer in the book is wrong:

Given $S=1+3+5+\cdots+2017+2019$, find $$\frac{1}{1010}S-1008$$

My attempt is:

$S=1+3+5+\cdots+2017+2019$

$S=\frac{2019-1}{2}(1+2019)$

$S=2038180$

Now I find
$$\frac{1}{1010}S-1008=\frac{1}{1010}2038180-1008=1010$$

But in the book answer is $2$. Where is my error, or is the answer in the book wrong? Help me please.

Comment: How did you get that $S=\frac{2019-1}{2}(1+2019)$?

Comment: Book is right, you miscounted the number of terms

Comment: The question title is almost a piece of comedy . The book is correct because $S=1010+2\sum_{i=1}^{1009} i  =1010\cdot\left(1+1009\right)=1010^2$.

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch Did you notice that only the odd terms are in the sum? The Book's answer is correct.

Comment: @PierreCarre Yes I did, please have a closer look at my comment .

Comment: @PierreCarre that is exactly what Maxi did right?

Comment: As a rule of thumb, the book is right.

Comment: @JustWandering Maxi tried to use the formula for the sum of terms in an arithmetic progression, so he also considered the even terms. He didn't quite compute that because the number of terms is 2019, not 2019-1.

Comment: @PierreCarre Please look once again . I never considered even terms. I used that $$S=\sum_{i=0}^{1009} (1+2i) = 1010+2\sum_{i=1}^{1009} i$$

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch I was not talking about your post! I was talking about the OP. Autocomplete is a pain... Madrit, not Maxi.

Comment: @PierreCarre Ooooh, I see 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$S_3:=1+3+5=9,\\\frac{S_3}3-(3-2)=2$$ and more generally

$$S_n=1+3+5+\cdots(2n-1)=n^2,\\\frac Sn-(n-2)=2.$$

Answer (score 1):

You could solve it as follows:

Each term is odd, so it may be written as $2n+1$. Noticing that $2019=2\cdot 1009+1$ The sum is then

> $$S=\sum_{n=0}^{1009}(2n+1)=2\sum_{n=0}^{1009}n+\sum_{n=0}^{1009}1$$

> $$S=2\left (\frac{1009\cdot 1010}{2}\right)+1010=1010^2$$

Thus, $$\frac{S}{1010}-1008=2$$

Comment: I think writing $1010^2$ is better than $1020100$

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch I agree; fixed!

Answer (score 0):

The answer is actually 2.
Assuming a=1, d=2;

```
  a+(n–1)d=2019
```

or, n–1=1009

```
>>n=1010
```

Now,
S=n/2×{2a+(n–1)d}

> > S=1010/2×{2+(1009×2)}

> > S=1010^2

Thus, (1010^2/1010)–1008=2

So, the answer is 2